Korea Transit Visa Bound to Australia
I’m a Philippine passport holder based in Dubai with an Australia subclass 600 visitor visa. I read that Philippine passport holders are allowed to stay in Korea without tourist visa if we have an onward flight to Australia. I am planning to transit to Korea and stay for a week without Korean tourist visa. My itinerary is Dubai to Korea with less than 24 hours layover in Shanghai then Korea to Australia. I just want to clarify if my flight from Korea to Australia should be a direct flight or flights with transit to other county is possible like maybe 4 hours? For example Incheon to Sydney but with 4 hours transit in Vietnam. Please advise. Thank you
